How to fix: "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity" with buildozer
Im using buildozer to create an android app with the bleak Python package.
After the build, running buildozer android deploy run logcat the app crashes after the splash screen.
In the log, it seems like the error is
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 10:18:47.401 20466 20466 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.bleuart, PID: 20466
10-30 10:18:47.401 20466 20466 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bleuart/com.example.bleuart.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Here a possible solution is laid out, but does anybody have any idea how to solve this using buildozer?
